# Windows Service Exception

Tags: wpf, windows-services

I have a windows service. And the below function is called during the service is started.

```
static public void SaveXpsPageToJpeg(string xpsFileName, int[] pages){
    using (XpsDocument xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(xpsFileName, System.IO.FileAccess.Read)){
        FixedDocumentSequence docSeq = xpsDoc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
        DocumentPaginator paginator = docSeq.DocumentPaginator;

        // You can get the total page count from docSeq.PageCount

        foreach(int pageNum in pages){
            using (DocumentPage docPage = paginator.GetPage(pageNum)){
                BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                RenderTargetBitmap renderTarget =
                    new RenderTargetBitmap((int)docPage.Size.Width,
                    (int)docPage.Size.Height,
                        96, // WPF (Avalon) units are 96dpi based
                        96,
                        System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default);

                renderTarget.Render(docPage.Visual);

                JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();  // Choose type here ie: JpegBitmapEncoder, etc
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTarget));

                using (FileStream pageOutStream = new FileStream(xpsDoc + ".Page" + pageNum + ".jpg", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)){
                    encoder.Save(pageOutStream);
                    pageOutStream.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The same code runs perfectly with the WPF application.
But when I debug the same in service its throws an exception

I have also added the screen shots of the exception and inner details

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/62/97453717.png/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/850/95569721.jpg/

I also tried changing the X64, X86 and AnyCPU in configuration Manager

I am using Visual Studio 2010, .Net Framework 4

Can anybody help out here

Comment: The images are missing. When I click on the links and then download image it gives a 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to find a solution myself.

Most project created by Visual Studio is set to MTA by default.
I had to run my code inside STA thread.

Finally...!